# Duvida sobre fatorial em C#

Tags: c#

Estou tentando resolver esse exercício de repetição:

> Faça um for que inicie uma variável n (número) como 1 e fatorial
>   (resultado) como 1 e varia n de 1 até 10.

Código:

```
int fatorial = 1;
for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++)
{

}
```

Não consigo de jeito nenhum. Já tentei de várias formas, mas sempre travo na hora de conseguir o fatorial de todos os números apenas com um looping. Alguém poderia me ajudar? :D

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatorial http://www.matematicadidatica.com.br/Fatorial.aspx, o q vc tentou?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o enunciado. Vc esta com dificuldade em fazer a fatoração é isso?

Comment: Perdão, erro no enunciado. Não era fatoração, mas sim fatorial XD. Mas já consegui resolver, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @GabrielIasi o "resolvido" do site é você aceitar uma resposta, como já fez. Isso já aponta que o problema da pergunta foi resolvido :) Nem precisa adicionar no titulo, o site funciona diferente de fóruns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int fatorial = 1;
for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++)
{
    fatorial*=n;
    Console.WriteLine(n+" fatorial= "+fatorial);
}
```

1 fatorial= 1

2 fatorial= 2

3 fatorial= 6

4 fatorial= 24

5 fatorial= 120

6 fatorial= 720

7 fatorial= 5040

8 fatorial= 40320

9 fatorial= 362880

10 fatorial= 3628800

Comment: Uau! que simples, muito obrigado!